# Terraform Azure mac address not being outputted after first apply

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

During terraform plan i see `mac_address: <computed>` under `azurerm_network_interface.ni` but when i try to print,I get empty string.

```
output "mac" {
  value = "${azurerm_network_interface.ni.mac_address}"
}
```

output

```
$ terraform apply

output
    mac =
```

Comment: What does the output look like specifically?

Comment: @MattSchuchard  ` mac= `

Comment: Any update? Or if it's helpful you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you just create the network interface and do not use it, it would not have the MAC address. See this in the [Note of creating the Network Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-network-interface#create-a-network-interface):

> Azure assigns a MAC address to the network interface only after the
>   network interface is attached to a virtual machine and the virtual
>   machine is started the first time.

If you want to output the MAC address in the Terraform through

```
azurerm_network_interface.ni.mac_address
```

You should attach it a VM and start the VM at least one time.

Comment: Even if I add depends_on to the output, we still don't get the mac_address. I have to re-apply to finally get the address.